How to find out that a conversation with a chatbot is likely ended
I'm working on a ChatBot with Python and langchain, and I'd like to have a metric that I could use to understand how close we are to the completion of a discussion.
So, for instance, that metric should score high if the last sentence of the history was Goodbye or I see that we both agree, or any other that somehow implies that the probability that we'll continue with the same topic is low.
Is there something that I can use on langchain or another library to help me with this?
